# change table gridview select wrong row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have page load to load gridview from database
and i have textbox and search button can change the gridview. but that problem is gridview_selectindexchanging select wrong row.

```
        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging1(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {

        lbl_1.Visible = true;
        lbl_2.Visible = true;
        lbl_3.Visible = true;
        lbl_4.Visible = true;
        lbl_5.Visible = true;
        lbl_6.Visible = true;
        lbl_7.Visible = true;
        btn_submit.Visible = true;
        lbl_nama.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        lbl_alamat.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text;
        lbl_hp.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[3].Text;
        lbl_kode.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[4].Text;
        lbl_peminjaman.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[5].Text;
        lbl_pengembalian.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[6].Text;

        DateTime kembali = DateTime.ParseExact(lbl_pengembalian.Text,"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (DateTime.Now > kembali)
        {
            lbl_denda.Text = "Rp.20000,-";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_denda.Text = "Rp.0,-";
        }
    }
```

and

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" style="text-align: left" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging1">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Be more specific and clarify what your question is? As of code above: `e.NewSelectedIndex` in `SelectedIndexChanging` event will return the new row being selected. If you want currently selected row then you should use `SelectedRow` property in `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: i have a gridview.and i made the data in gridview can change like sorting or searching. The problem occurs when users try to select a row after they sorted the data. I can see that the gridview kinda "forgets" how the rows were sorted and selects the row that was at the clicked index before it got sorted..how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for the `EnablePersistedSelection` property.

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the selection  of a row is
>   based on index or on data-key values
>
> If this property is false and a row is selected, the same row  is
>   selected when a new page is displayed even though the new  page has
>   different data in it. If you set this property to true,  when you
>   display a page that has different data in it, no row is selected.  If
>   you then return to the page on which a row was selected,  that row is
>   still selected.