# gridview get wrong row in selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have 2 sql to select the table.program running grid view show number 1 sql.

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn_submit.Visible = false;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HENDRICK-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mylibrary.com;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "select * from PEMINJAMAN";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        GridView1.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataBind();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

but i can change sql1 to sql2 just click the button.

```
        protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            close();
            GridView1.DataSource = null;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            lbl_error.Visible = false;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HENDRICK-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mylibrary.com;Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "select * from PEMINJAMAN where NAMA_PEMINJAM like '" + txt_search.Text + "%' or ALAMAT_PEMINJAM like '" + txt_search.Text + "%' or HP_PEMINJAM like '" + txt_search.Text + "%' or KODE_BUKU like '" + txt_search.Text + "%' or TGL_PINJAM like '" + txt_search.Text + "%' or TGL_KEMBALI like '" + txt_search.Text + "%'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            GridView1.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();
            conn.Close();                
        }
        catch 
        {
            lbl_error.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

and i must to get data from gridviewselectrow. but the problem is the event get the wrong row.i change the gridview to sql2 and i select the row but gridview  change automatic to sql1 and take row from sql1.not sql2.it's my gridview event

```
        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging1(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        btn_submit.Visible = true;
        lbl_nama.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        lbl_alamat.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text;
        lbl_hp.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[3].Text;
        lbl_kode.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[4].Text;
        lbl_peminjaman.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[5].Text;
        lbl_pengembalian.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[6].Text;

        DateTime kembali = DateTime.ParseExact(lbl_pengembalian.Text,"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (DateTime.Now > kembali)
        {
            lbl_denda.Text = "Rp.20000,-";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_denda.Text = "Rp.0,-";
        }
    }
```

and its my gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" style="text-align: left" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging1">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

how to fix it?sorry my english so bad. thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change table gridview select wrong row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155617/change-table-gridview-select-wrong-row)

Answer (score 0):

**`SelectedIndexChanging`** events returns you the new row being selected and not the currently selected row, here you may cancel the selection. For getting the currently selected row you must use the **`SelectedIndexChanged`** event and access it via **`SelectedRow`**.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn_submit.Visible = true;
    lbl_nama.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    ....
}
```